# Is the none() step supported in Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I'm building a system for composable traversals in my app and have a case where the [none() step](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#none-step) would be helpful. I need to explicitly return no traversal. It does not seem to be implemented in Gremlin javascript.

> "errorType": "TypeError", "errorMessage": "o.none is not a function"

Is there a reason this has been omitted? Should it not be used? I'm working around it by using `hasId("x")` which should never exist and thus return no traversal, but it's a hack.

```
      g.V().choose(
        hasCommentingUnlocked({
          traversal: hasAccessToPrivateUserData({
            traversal: __,
            isAdmin,
            userId,
            grantedTraversal: __.identity(),
            declinedTraversal: __.hasId("x"), // __.none() would be helpful here
          }),
          P,
        }),
        __.constant(true),
        __.constant(false)
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`none()` should probably be [implemented for consistency](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2500) in gremlin-javascript, but it really is more of an internal step to be used as a marker for `iterate()` which filters all results. When the server sees `none()` it knows that `iterate()` is called. That said, the adage I've learned from years of open source software development is "if you build it, people will use it" so `none()` has come to find some use cases.

Of course, it's hard to say if your use case is one that needs `none()` given your example. I tend to find the use case for `none()` fairly narrow so it wouldn't surprise me at all to find another way to write your traversal to avoid using it in the first place.